# Does this CSS generate extra HTTP requests?

Tags: css, http

I have a pretty simple question: I am using the filter property as a fallback in IE for background-size:cover, here's an example:

```
<div id="foo" style="
   background-image:url('image.png')
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.png', sizingMethod='scale');">
</div>
```

I have a doubt: would this generate extra HTTP requests?

Comment: CSS requested only once(if it's changed it will load new one of course) after that code will be read by browser. So this is just an understandable code for IE thats all.

Comment: @mithataydogmus: But when you specify other resources from within CSS the browser will generate requests for those resources.

Comment: image.png already cached so there won't be problem. At least in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As far as I know, other browsers won't even look at the `filter` property, and even if they did, the `image.png` would already be fetched and cached.